# Error using httpclient on vertx

Tags: java, rest, networking, vert.x

Hello i'm trying to perform a rest call on a distant ressources using the code bellow. on vertx 3.3.3 it works with defaulthttpclient (appache) but it's not asynchron

i still get the error:
nov. 01, 2016 8:15:08 AM io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestImpl
GRAVE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:80

```
final HttpClient httpClient = vertx.createHttpClient();

        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(uri);

        httpClient.request(apiMethod.getHttpMethod(), uri, resultHandler -> {
            resultHandler.statusCode();
            if (resultHandler.statusCode() == 200) {
                environment.setStatus(ApiStatus.OK);
                apiMethod.setStatus(ApiStatus.OK);
            } else {
                environment.setStatus(ApiStatus.ERROR);
                apiMethod.setStatus(ApiStatus.ERROR);
            }
            resultHandler.bodyHandler(buffer -> {
                String message = "";
                logger.debug("Output from Server .... \n");
                logger.debug(buffer);
                message = buffer.toString();
                apiMethod.setCallingDate(new Date());
                apiMethod.setCallingResult(message);
            });
        }).putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end();
```

Can anyone help?

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're forgetting to configure the client to which host and port to connect to and it is using the default values `localhost:80` as you can read from the exception.

You should be doing something like:

```
httpClient.request(GET, "www.yourserver.com", 80, uri, res -> {
  ...
});
```

Note that `uri` is not an `URL` so it should be something like:

```
/api/users?from=5&to=10
```

If you're looking for a more compact version then what you should be using is the `requestAbs` method:

```
httpClient
  .requestAbs(GET, "http://www.yourserver.com/api/users?from=5&to=10", res -> {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: hello Paulo thanks for the comment it seems like using requestAbs is the correct one, but now i get a message "connection closed" is there any other parameter to change?

Comment: @Paulo Lopez - do you know how to wrap this in a Future?